# Group by Date part only in LINQ to MySql in entity framework

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, entity-framework-5

I have been trying to group a table data `Date` wise while ignoring `time` part. As i need the no of `count` date wise in my data source. For all this i have tried many options but fails.

**My First Attempt**

```
var data1 = from p in context.qry_view_record
            where p.INT_ITEM_ID == 1                          
            group p by p.DAT_VIEW_START.Date into g
            select new { ViewDate = g.Key, Count = g.Count() };
```

Fail with Exception `The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.`

**Second Attempt**

I tried using `EntityFunctions` class to modify the query as

```
 var data1 = from p in context.qry_view_record
             where p.INT_ITEM_ID == 1                          
             group p by EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(p.DAT_VIEW_START) into g
             select new { ViewDate = g.Key, Count = g.Count() };
```

Fail with Exception `FUNCTION Mynamespace.TruncateTime does not exist`

**Third Attempt**

I tried creating a `User defined MySql Function and stored procedure` to truncate the time part and import the procedure as `FunctionImport`

```
var data1 = from p in context.qry_view_record
            where p.INT_ITEM_ID == 1                          
            group p by context.sp_getDate(p.DAT_VIEW_START) into g
            select new { ViewDate = g.Key, Count = g.Count() };
```

Failed with Exception `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult`1[System.Nullable1[System.DateTime]] sp_getDate(System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]) method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

Please suggest any workaround..

Answer (score -1):

Use 
`System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime` 
instead of 
`EntityFunctions.TruncateTime` 
in the second attempt.

Comment: I am using `EF 5.0`. So `DbFunction` class not available.. Stick to `EF 5.0` due Mysql Compatibility issues in `EF 6.0`